# Getting error converted oracle index to postgresql

Tags: postgresql-14

we are in the process of migrating oracle to postgresql. during the process we are getting error for the below index.

Oracle Index: CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 (column1||'-A1' ASC) ;

By using schema tool the above index automatically converted into like below. when we try to execute it and getting exception like below.

Postgresql:

CREATE INDEX idx1 ON table1 USING BTREE (CONCAT_WS() ASC);

Error: ERROR:function concat_ws() does not exist LINE 3: USING BTREE (CONCAT_WS() ASC)

Can someone suggest how to match the oracle index to postgresql:

Comment: Any migration tool is not 100% prefect  you must need to  do some manual intervention into the migration process. Index get created on column, not methods/function. The PostgreSQL CREATE INDEX is having CONCATE_WS() which is method not function. Replace it with column name and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
CREATE INDEX my_ix ON test USING BTREE ((x || '-a1') ASC);
```

Note the extra brackets! The `USING BTREE` and the `ASC` are optional as they are the defaults.

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/PAA_geLW).